# adb shell dumpsys window windows output not showing mCurrentFocused

Tags: python, android, adb, dumpsys

I am using

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows
```

command but the output is not showing mCurrentFocused
using Virtual device Nexus 6P API 30
Kindly help me out or alternate command

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below command, worked for me to get appPackage/appActivity   (com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main - For Chrome Browser)

dumpsys activity | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'